# How do I change the date format in the formula bar to match cells in excel

Tags: excel, date, formatting

I am trying to format a date column so i can compare another list and sort for duplicates. The format I need to match is mm/yyyy. I have changed the format through a custom format however the formula bar still shows m/dd/yyyy even though it shows correctly in the cell. Because of this, the dup function (count if) is checking the formula bar but not what shows in the cell. I would assume that this is a simple fix? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The COUNTIF looks at the raw value not hte cell display value or the formula bar value. If you have a problem with countif(s) then it is elsewhere. Probably comparing text-that-looks-like-a-date to a real date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to change the date format from a true date to text.

```
=TEXT(A1,"mm/yyyy")
```

But if you want to leave the dates as real dates and you want to count the number of dates that are in the month of April 2017.  You can book end the dates with COUNTIFS():

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">=" & DATE(2017,4,1),A:A,"<" & Date(2017,5,1))
```

Comment: Congrats on that gold [tag:excel-formula] hammer!

Comment: Just waiting for you, Pnuts and I are the only two.

Comment: @JNC please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.